# Radiation of a charged particle

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Take a uncharged particle. It hits a resting charged particle. Will the charged particle radiate then?

Comment: Could you give us some context? Why does it matter whether the projectile is uncharged? Why are you in doubt about whether there is radiation?

Answer (score 0):

As the charged particle quickly/instantaneously accelerates from rest into motion, due to the collision, it will radiate.

Answer (score 0):

If one speaks about a neutron and a proton (or also an electron), in a collision an exchange of impulses occurs between them, minus a loss of energy.

In the sentence above there are some remarkable details:

- It doesn't matter whether the charge or the neutral particle moves in relation to the observer, only the relative motion between them is relevant.
- The second law of thermodynamics was based on this phenomenon; any energy exchange is accompanied by an energy loss in the form of electromagnetic radiation. The sum of impulses after collision is less that sum before collision.
- It does not matter at all, is the particle charged or not; even for two neutrons an energy loss occurs.

> Will the charged particle emit then?

It is more the case that the the energy exchange is accompanied by an energy loss.